# Executing virus in VIRTUAL MACHINE

Tags: virtual-machine, virus

I want to execute a malware file in the virtual environment OS which i am using in Windows XP.
But when i try that, my Kaspersky on my pc detects the threat and deletes it.

Do you know any other way, apart from disabling Kaspersky ?

Comment: Woah, those antivirus programs worked for once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaspersky should not be able to detect the virus in the virtual machine itself, just the virus on your pc.

There isn't really a lot you can do other than disabling Kaspersky or using an exclusion on the folder that contains the malware that you want to copy to the virtual machine.

A much safer way, is to bypass Kaspersky all together and download/get the malware direct from the source to the virtual machine directly.

Comment: I think Kaspersky is scanning network traffic because when I go to virus page in the VM it shows the page blocked inside the VM and as a notification on the host

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way than disabling Kaspersky, except by getting the virus directly into the VM without passing through the PC host.

For example, in the VM you can download it from the internet thru a service such as Dropbox.